# How to customize MongoRepository without overriding the annotated @Query methods in interface?

Tags: mongodb, repository, spring-data-mongodb

I want to customize MongoRepository by adding one method, and still using the implemented methods provided by MongoRepository. Below is the code:

```
public interface TopoRepositoryInterface extends MongoRepository<Topo, String>
{
    @Query("{'name':?0}")
    public Topo findByName(String name);

    public long getPublishedTopoCount();
}
```

the implementation declaration is:

```
public class TopoRepositoryImpl extends SimpleMongoRepository<Topo, String> implements TopoRepositoryInterface
```

If without the customization,  method findByName declared in TopoRepositoryInterface can be automatically implemented by adding @Query("{'name':?0}") annotation. But now, since there is interface inheritage, I must add code

```
@Override
public Topo findByName(String name)
{
    Topo topo = getMongoOperations().findOne(Query.query(Criteria.where("name").is(name)), Topo.class);
    return topo;
}
```

Is there any way to write my own code for getPublishedTopoCount() only, and leave findByName() be implemented by @Query annotation? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 4):

You have to split your repository interface into two.

First one - "Custom" containing methods you implement manually would be:

```
public interface TopRepositoryCustom {
    long getPublishedTopoCount();
}
```

Second one for generated methods:

```
public interface TopRepository extends MongoRepository<Topo, String>, TopRepositoryCustom {
    @Query("{'name':?0}")
    Topo findByName(String name);  
}
```

Then you just need to implement first repository and remember to follow proper naming convention. See more at: [spring-data mongodb custom implementation PropertyReferenceException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17035419/spring-data-mongodb-custom-implementation-propertyreferenceexception) and [Spring Data MongoDB Custom implementations reference](http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-document/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations)