# spring-data mongodb custom implementation PropertyReferenceException

Tags: spring, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

I'm trying to implement a custom query according to the Reference 4.4 Custom Implementations:

http://static.springsource.org/spring-data/data-mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/repositories.html

[What's the difference between Spring Data's MongoTemplate and MongoRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/spring-data-mongotemplate-vs-mongorepository)

I'm doing this because I need special queries using mongoTemplate.

The error I'm getting is a PropertyReferenceException. So it seems that spring-data is trying to auto-generate the query which I don't want. I want to use my own custom query.

```
org.springframework.data.mapping.PropertyReferenceException: No property search found for type com.eerra.core.common.dto.User
```

The problem is described also here but the solution doesn't seem to work for me:

http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?114454-Custom-repository-functionality

**Question**

How can I implement my custom query interface and implementation without spring-data trying to auto-generate the query?

**Configuration**

***Spring Configuration***

*spring-data.xml*

```
<!-- Spring Data MongoDB repository support -->
<mongo:repositories base-package="com.eerra.*.common.service" />
```

The Repository classes and interfaces are located in following package:

com.eerra.core.common.service.UserRepositoryInterface.java
com.eerra.core.common.service.UserRepoistoryCustom.java (interface)
com.eerra.core.common.service.UserRepositoryCustomImpl.java (implementation)

**UserRepositoryCustom.java**

```
public interface UserRepositoryCustom {
    List<User> searchAllUsers();
}
```

**UserRepositoryCustomImpl.java**

```
public class UserRepositoryCustomImpl implements UserRepositoryCustom {

    @Autowired
    private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

    @Override
    public List<User> searchAllUsers() {
        return mongoTemplate.findAll(User.class);
    }
}
```

**UserRepositoryInterface.java**

```
@Repository
public interface UserRepositoryInterface extends MongoRepository<User, String>, UserRepositoryCustom {
    User findByEmail(String email);
    List<User> findByEmailLike(String email);
    List<User> findByEmailOrLastName(String email, String lastName);
    List<User> findByEmailOrFirstNameLike(String email, String firstName);

    @Query("{\"$or\" : [ { \"email\" : { \"$regex\" : ?0, \"$options\" : \"i\"}} , " +
        "{ \"firstName\" : { \"$regex\" : ?0, \"$options\" : \"i\"}}, " +
        "{ \"lastName\" : { \"$regex\" : ?0, \"$options\" : \"i\"}}]}")
    List<User> findByEmailOrFirstNameOrLastNameLike(String searchText);
}
```

Comment: For future readers, if you use single quote in the JSON query you don't have to escape the characters: `{ 'email': ?0 }` instead of `{ \"email\": ?0 }`

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The problem is solved. This error appears when the Impl class is named incorrectly. The Impl class has to be named according to the repository class. So the names have to be following for this example:

- com.eerra.core.common.service.UserRepositoryInterface.java (main repository)
- com.eerra.core.common.service.UserRepositoryInterfaceImpl.java (implementation of custom repository methods)
- com.eerra.core.common.service.UserRepositoryInterfaceCustom.java (interface with custom methods)

See the answer here:
[What's the difference between Spring Data's MongoTemplate and MongoRepository?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17008947/spring-data-mongotemplate-vs-mongorepository)