# Is it possible to give default value for a @Query method in a spring mongodb repository?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

```
@Query( "{ 'name': { $eq: ?0 } }" )
List<OrderInfo> findIt( @Param("p") @DefaultValue("Bart") String x );
```

I try it, but not working.

Comment: You can implement a  custom query for that particular repository object.

Comment: Yes.If just write query statement, that would be happy:D

Comment: Here is documentation about [Custom Implementations for Spring Data Repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.custom-implementations) and a post: [How to customize MongoRepository without overriding the annotated @Query methods in interface?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17006998/how-to-customize-mongorepository-without-overriding-the-annotated-query-methods).